# websockex: Error to connect ssl sockets with a CRLF json protocol

Tags: sockets, websocket, erlang, elixir

I'm trying to connect to a socket (ssl) using [websockex](https://github.com/Azolo/websockex)

```
defmodule WebSocketExample do
  use WebSockex

  def start_link(url, state) do
    WebSockex.start_link(url, __MODULE__, state)
  end

  def handle_frame({type, msg}, state) do
    IO.puts("Received Message - Type: #{inspect(type)} -- Message: #{inspect(msg)}")
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_cast({:send, {type, msg} = frame}, state) do
    IO.puts("Sending #{type} frame with payload: #{msg}")
    {:reply, frame, state}
  end
end
```

```
WebSocketExample.start_link "wss://stream-api.betfair.com", :state
```

But it returns `{:error, %WebSockex.ConnError{original: :closed}}`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Does `curl` work in the first place? You are asking questions about some 3rd-party libraries I doubt anyone around ever has heard about. Could you start with proof that the remote works as expected when connecting via WebSocket? Like, as I said, providing the exact `curl` request that does indeed work.

Comment: `openssl s_client -no_tls1 -no_ssl3 -connect stream-api.betfair.com:443` works like a charm

Comment: So you pass 3 additional parameters in call to `openssl`. How about switching `debug` option on https://hexdocs.pm/websockex/WebSockex.html#t:option/0 and see what’s the cause of an issue? I suspect at least [`insecure`](https://hexdocs.pm/websockex/WebSockex.Conn.html#t:connection_option/0) option to be set, or something.

Comment: I've tryied, but I can't connect. I did set `insecure: false` and `:cacerts`

Comment: I honestly cannot understand what do you need. If you need to connect, there is plain old good 30yo `:ssl` erlang module, that perfectly does its job `:ssl.connect('stream-api.betfair.com', 443, [:binary], 1_000) #⇒ {:ok, {:sslsocket, {:gen_tcp, #Port<0.15>, :tls_connection, :undefined}, [#PID<0.249.0>, #PID<0.248.0>]}}`.

Comment: `ssl.connect('stream-api.betfair.com', 443, [:binary], 1_000)` returns `{:error, :timeout}`

Comment: Do you want me to post a screenshot? It perfectly works. Make sure you have started `:ssl` by calling `Application.ensure_all_started(:ssl)`, but if it was not started, it’d return `{:error, :ssl_not_started}`. Make also sure you manage your proxy or whatever might prevent from connecting there. Also, try to increase a timeout.

Comment: Screenshot:  https://ibb.co/Vq7HjJx

Comment: What works forme: `sock = fn() -> {:ok, s} = :gen_tcp.connect('stream-api-integration.betfair.com', 443, []); s; end` `:ssl.connect(sock.(), [])`

Comment: It’s extremely weird. But since `:ssl.connect/4`  works here and I am unable to find a way to break it, I hardly can help to debug.

Comment: I can only think about OS. Are you on Mac? They always have been having a permanently broken SSL support, but not on _that_ level.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on mac.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin it works now. I don't no why. https://ibb.co/4WTHCGP

Comment: So, what the best way to handle(send and receive) msgs I need to authenticate

Comment:  I personally would fork https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket (it looks pretty mature, but not fully covering the real-world diversity,) and update it to understand the betfair.com format. It should not be rather complicated and it would save you time on the boilerplate.